# Fail on update a mediumblob value in MariaDB database

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mariadb, ado

I am using a MariaDB database on server side with MS Access frontend. I try to upload a binary file in my database in nomappdata table with this structure:

ID       int(11)
appCode    mediumblob

The function used to upload is:

```
Function saveFileToDB(ID As Long, fName As String)

Dim myConn As New ADODB.connection
Dim rsADO As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim st As New ADODB.Stream

On Error Resume Next

strSQL = "SELECT nomappdata.* FROM nomappdata WHERE ID = " & ID

With myConn
    .ConnectionString = getConnStrMySQL("N")
    .Open
End With

If myConn.Errors.Count = 0 Then

    With rsADO
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .ActiveConnection = myConn
        .Open strSQL

    End With
    
    With st
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile fName
    End With
    
    With rsADO
        .Fields("appCode").Value = st.Read
        .Update
    End With

End If

st.Close
Set st = Nothing
rsADO.Close
Set rsADO = Nothing
myConn.Close
Set myConn = Nothing
End Function
```

The test file size what I trying to upload is about 73 kByte.

The connection worked (State = 1 )

The stream object loaded the file data (tested)

The recordset was read (tested)

The script working fine for files with size less than 64 kBytes but I need to delete the previous value before update because if not, the update doesn't work.

My problem is when the debug promt reach the ".Update" line, access is waiting for a while then crashing unexpectedly.
How can I solve this problem ?

I'm using the following software:

Microsoft Access for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13001.20338) 64 bit
MariaDB 10.1.40-MariaDB
mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.9-win64

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "D:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "D:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "D:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
```

Modified (working) code:

```
Dim fileData() As Byte

With st
    .Type = adTypeBinary
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile fName
End With


With rsADO
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .ActiveConnection = myConn
    .Open strSQL
    .Fields("appCode").Value = st.Read
    .Update
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Does crashing imply there is a server and/or application error? Which one(s)? Increasing the mariadb server setting max_allowed_packet sounds like a preduent thing to do when updating larger files/blobs.

Comment: The MS Access application crashing.  I changed this to 16777216 (16M)  but the situation is the same.

Comment: [On Error Resmue Next](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/11022/resume-keyword) on top of a function is evil (only hides errors, that should be solved) and avoid [Auto-assigned objects](https://rubberduckvba.com/Features/FeatureItem/SelfAssignedDeclaration)(Dim obj as **New** Object)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug ([ODBC-251](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/ODBC-251?attachmentViewMode=list)) in "MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver".

Use "MySQL/ODBC Connector 8.0.19" (or newer) instead!

Alternatives:

1. Use [LOAD_FILE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load_file/) function
2. Store Data in filesystem and only store path to in db.

Comment: Thank you ComputerVersteher for your answer. I know the "evil"  in the Resume Next statement , in original code I have included an error handling part which isn't included in the code above for simplicity, but unfortunately doesn't show anything related to my problem. I looked after the max_text_repl_size (or something like this) but didn't find anything among my server variables. Also I tried to modification suggested by you but the situation doesn't change.

Comment: `max_allowed_packet`should be the right setting. You restarted MariaDB after changing? Show (in question) App versions of MS-Access. MariaDB, OS and ODBC driver! Also show relevant parts of MariaDB config file.

Comment: Hello @ComputerVersteher, after I changed the max_allowed_packet, I restarted the MariaDB server. I attached the version infos and a part of my.ini config file above, in my question.

Comment: Sorry ComputerVersteher for my careless, I will try the suggested options and will back with the results. Thank you !

Comment: Finally with some modification my code started to work ! Thank you for the solution and for your time. 

I use {MYSQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver} with the following connection string:

DRIVER={MYSQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver}; DATABASE=mydb; UID=myuser; PWD=mypasswd;SERVER=myserver;OPTION=67108922;CONN_TIMEOUT=5;Persist Security Info=true

Comment: Also I have some modification in code (above, at the end of my question). When I tryed to use .Fields("appCode").Value = st.Read the upddate wasn't successful, I don't understand why, but this code works perfectly.